# Preact and Webpack for Production

Tags: reactjs, webpack, preact

Just trying to make sure I am setting up my preact js correct for production.

In my webpack setup with preact, and run npm run build I notice with Bundle Analyzer Plugin the path for the preact js file is

`/node_modules/preact/dist/preact.js` and not

```
/node_modules/preact/dist/preact.min.js
```

I have uglify and minify js set up as well, but just thought it was curious that the minified package is not picked up ?

Entry script within webpack

```
  entry: { app: './src/index.js', vendor: [ 'preact', 'preact-router' ] },
```

Npm Run build script

```
   "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress -p --display-modules --display-chunks"
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `main` for preact is `dist/preact.js` - `preact.min.js` is there for people who want to take advantage of minification when not applying their own (people hotlinking it off a CDN, for example), and to measure real-world output size.

You're already applying UglifyJS to your bundle by running `webpack` with the `-p` flag, so you needn't worry too much about trying to use `dist/preact.min.js`.  It could save a few bytes, but nothing major.  The file you're using (`dist/preact.js`) is actually already run through UglifyJS by Preact, it's just not compressed but not mangled (so the variable names remain intact).